# Mac OS boots slowly after replacing SSD

Tags: macos, ssd

When I press the power button on my Mac, the screen is empty for about 30 seconds, then the Apple logo with a progressbar appears, and after 10 more seconds the log-in screen is shown.

The 30 seconds delay started occurring after I replaced my Samsung 840 ssd by Samsung 850. (I cloned one SSD to another one in CarbonCopyCloner).

Can I remove that delay by running some commands / apps?
(Or is the 850-ssd generally slower than 840-series)?

Comment: Have you actually selected your boot volume as Startup Disk in System prefs? Sounds like you didn't & it's still looking for the old one first, before it gives up & has a look around for something it can boot from

Comment: Let me throw it in as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess would be that the Mac is still looking for the old boot drive, as the new one hasn't yet been 'blessed'.
It will hunt around for it for a while, then give up & try to find anything it can boot from - that's the point at which it finds the new drive & progresses.

System Prefs > Startup Disk...
Set your new drive as default then Restart...